# why is php trying to use 4GB to bind_results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting the strangest error.  First here is my very simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
    </header>
    <body>


        <?php
            require_once 'includes/config.php';


            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATA);
            if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

            //get safety sheat fields
            $query="SELECT `fields` FROM `subforms` WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 1";
            $stmt =  $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_result($fields);
            $stmt->execute();
            if (!$stmt->fetch()) {
                echo 'error: no such form';
                die();
            }
            die();
```

very simple.  the require gets the constants for the mysql database nothing more.

This code works fine on my xampp setup but when I put it on the linux server i get:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /home/[path to files I don't wish to make public]/test.php on line 20
```

Line 20 `$stmt->bind_result($fields);`

I really don't understand how that is even possible nor have the slightest clue where to look to figure out how to fix.  Any ideas?

Comment: very odd indeed, by the way, what is the data type of `fields`

Comment: longtext which explains the 4GB.

Comment: might be related, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#101543

Comment: well the answer below worked to resolve that issue but ended up causing the data to get truncated after the a in the serialised data stored in the field.  Changing the field to mediumtext fixed everything and I don't likely need more then 16MB anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding

`$stmt->store_result();`

before the `bind_result` line.  still very strange that it trys to reserve the entire 4GB a longtext can possibly store.  Guess I do need to increase ram or shrink field just incase the field gets filled up.